# Any Way to Speed Up JAXB Marshalling?

Tags: xml, jaxb, schema, marshalling

Is there any way to speed up a call to the **JAXB** `Marshaller.marshal(Object, OutputStream)`?

The project I'm working on is using JAXB to [un]marshal objects with a fairly large XML schema.  The call `someJaxbMarshaller.marshal(results, out)` takes 2 seconds to complete.  Everything else (JPA fetching, spatial filtering, quite a bit of other logic) takes only about 1 second.  So the use of JAXB is tripling my request response time.  I'm caching the JAXBContext and Marshaller objects, to speed things up as much as I can.  It's only the actual marshalling that is slowing me down.  Any suggestions?

I'm using **JAXB 2.2.3u1**, bundled with **JAX-WS 2.2.3**.  Newer versions seem to break multiple things, so we're locked into that version of JAXB (overriding the Java-included *JAX-WS 2.2.5* which uses *JAXB 2.2.4u1* - which we can't use, as it throws a `NullPointerException` on load).  We're also on **JDK 1.3.0_30**, and this is being run in *Eclipse Indigo*.  I saw a suggestion to use Woodstox, but *JAX-WS 2.2.3* already includes it.  I tried swapping it out with the newest version, but that slowed down marshalling by ~0.2 seconds.  Removing Woodstox had exactly the same performance as using the version included with JAX-WS.

The schema backing the objects being marshalled is about **5 MB** in size.  The actual XML document that JAXB generates is **117 KB** in size.

Comment: There is the potential that the JPA implementation is using lazy loading (JPA part appears really fast since it is deferring the work of realizing the relationships).  This would mean that the JAXB part needs to trigger the lazy relationships (JPA does the work, JAXB appears slow).

Comment: I considered this a few days ago, so I wrote a few nested loops to crawl through the JPA results and get all the primitive values (presumably forcing it to "fetch" everything it might be lazily deferring).  That set of loops completes in ~0.05 seconds, and the marshal time still takes 2 to 2.5 seconds.

Comment: What kind of OutputStream are you marshalling to (does file access factor in)?  Do you have a schema set on the Marshaller (validation slows down marshalling)?  Are you formatting the output (formatted is slower than non formatted)?  Did you specify an encoding other than UTF-8 (some JAXB implementations) optimise for UTF-8)?  I believe the JAXB RI lazily initialized some metadata, do you notice that the second marshal is faster?

Comment: You were right: Hibernate was at fault.  I had assumed that my crawl through (prior to JAXB marshalling) to print all the primitives would ensure everything was already fetched.  But a few days ago, I added annotations that told Hibernate to get everything right then, which simply moved the delay from marshal time to beforehand.  Now to figure out how to get Hibernate to actually fetch everything in one shot instead of piecemeal, as it has over 600 tables to work with...